# How to include sticky session in AWS Elastic Beanstalk using Cloud Formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudformation, sticky-sessions

As I searched for the stickiness in Elastic Beanstalk I didn't find the way how to include it using AWS Cloud Formation. Can anyone help me to do that thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to configure ALB settings in Cloudformation, but you can use Elastic Beanstalk [namespaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html#environments-cfg-alb-namespaces) to configure load balancer settings.

**.ebextensions/alb-default-process.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
    DeregistrationDelay: '20'
    HealthCheckInterval: '15'
    HealthCheckPath: /
    HealthCheckTimeout: '5'
    HealthyThresholdCount: '3'
    UnhealthyThresholdCount: '5'
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
    StickinessEnabled: 'true'
    StickinessLBCookieDuration: '43200'
```